# How is this design pattern called?

Tags: php, design-patterns

How do you call this design pattern?

```
class Foo {
   protected $delegates = array();
   //...
   public function __call($method,$argv) {
      //call $this->$something->$method($argv), where $something is a mapping from $this->delegates
   }
}
```

I can speculate, but I'm not sure, so I wanted to ask you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aptly named [Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)?

Comment: Are you saying that only because the member's name, or did I really named it right? :)

Comment: Because you used the word 'delegates' in your example. :)

Comment: Could someone confirm? I don't trust my naming convention :-)

Comment: Oh, I misread what you were asking. Click the name in my reply, and you'll see that it leads to the Wikipedia page specifically about the pattern; it's definitely the correct name.